# Worried about fumes from caulk

Tags: safety, caulking

Hey there I just installed caulk due to the baseboards having room under them (the roaches are hiding in there) my question and concern is of the fume smell from this particular one https://www.gorillatough.com/wp-content/uploads/Gorilla-Sealant-White-100-Silicone-Sealant-v1.4-08122020.pdf

I’m very new to this sort of thing but the smell is next level and I’m wondering if it’s toxic to inhale or if it can harm you when you breathe it in. Is it safe to remain in the same room as it overnight?

Comment: Usually it is a vinegar/acetic acid smell as it sets.  Opening a window a bit should reduce the smell.  It should be gone in a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

Per the MSDS you linked, while there are small amounts of other things, the primary odor is claimed to be acetic acid (*i.e.* vinegar) which is pretty common for household silicone caulking formulations while curing. If it's bothering you, you should probably ventilate more - open a window, turn on an exhaust fan, do both. The MSDS does mention eye and respiratory irritation, which acetic acid fumes will certainly do.

That should dissapate in a day or two as the caulk hardens. If ventilation does not prove adequate for your comfort, visit a friend or otherwise get out of the place.